# fixing error for tutorial

Tags: android

I am trying to implement [this](http://www.artfulbits.com/articles/samples/aicharts/sample-viewer.aspx?sample=ECGSample) tutorial . But i am getting error  on

```
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.ChartView;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartArea;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartAxisStripLine;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartPointCollection;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartSeries;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Types.ChartStepLineType;
```

The sample can be downloaded from the link mentioned . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not really a tutorial. It is just a sample.

They show the sample, so that people can see how to use their charts in an Android application. But the thing is that they use their own charts API, which they sell commercially. So basically you cannot get much out of this example.

You can either [ask them for a tryout](http://ww.artfulbits.com/products/android/try/aicharts.aspx), by providing your information (although that will just give you the .apk file for you to see running in your device, rather than the API source), or you can just create some mock classes based on their sample, and fill them partially to try and achieve a similar effect.

In any case, regardless which approach you take, it will not work like a tutorial. You will have to explore it out.

So regarding charts i think it would be better for you to find another source, with proper tutorials, either for open source or free chart libraries, or for how to create your own.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern , please guide if there is any other open source . Once again thanks for your concern .

Comment: You have quite some alternatives. Many of which are open source, such as http://www.achartengine.org/ or http://androidplot.com/wiki/Home 
You also can find additional alternatives in some other posts such as:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271248/how-to-draw-charts-in-android